# По первому взгляду и виду(,) / Несложная, кажется, вещь

Tags: запятые

Нужны эти запятые в песне Боярского «Что будет, то будет!»?

> По первому взгляду и виду(,) / Несложная, кажется, вещь / — Роскошную эту равнину / Верхом не спеша пересечь.

Comment: А что, есть варианты?  В тексте стоит запятая: По первому взгляду и виду, Не трудная кажется вещь, Роскошную эту равнину Верхом не спеша пересечь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант **с обособлением:**

***По первому взгляду и виду**,*

*Несложная, кажется, вещь —*

*Роскошную эту равнину*

*Верхом не спеша пересечь.*

**Грамматика предложения**:  *Несложная вещь — пересечь (равнину).*

Простое предложение, распространенное. **Тире** между подлежащим и сказуемым.

**Обстоятельственный оборот** относится ко всему предложению. В общем случае обособление **факультативное**, но здесь лучше обособить ввиду **распространенности** предложения и оборота.

Оборот равнозначен **придаточному условия**: если посмотреть (первый взгляд).

Answer (score 1):

"По первому взгляду и виду" — кривоватый набор слов, не имеющий прецедентов.

Но обособления не требует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*По первому взгляду и виду*

Несложная, кажется, вещь —

Роскошную эту равнину

*Верхом не спеша пересечь.*